# How to build a cross-platform html5 application for android

Tags: android, html, cross-platform

I'm new to android development and after scanning the web for this particular issue i'm still confused about how to develop an html5 cross-platform application? Can i do it using eclipse? What are my possibilities? Could you inform me what should I go through and where exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Eclipse is fine; Google provides an all-in-one package, see http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download; for a HTML/JavaScript app your could have a look at PhoneGap (http://phonegap.com/). They have really good tutorials for beginners. 
Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap for an overview of features.

There are others e.g. Titanium or Appcelerator (see http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use PhoneGap. Visit http://phonegap.com/. It will let you develop cross platform applications using html, css and javasccript.

Also this is the "getting started" page of PhoneGap API.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Cordova plugin:
http://cordova.apache.org/

Happy coding :D

Comment: thanks, and what is Cordova? and could you please explain how the development is done? do i write my code over eclipse or over some other program? also, what is the role of phonegap in my development?

Comment: Cordova is a plugin some sort of api library for android that I think used by phonegap, this allows a mobile app developer to access native device functions. If you don't want to code java then phonegap is good for you. The advantage of phonegap is for rapid deployment and makes your life easier if you want your app to be available in cross platform. I updated my post and included the Cordova information page.

Comment: Cordova is a deviation of PhoneGap (see http://www.simb.net/2012/03/19/phonegap-vs-callback-vs-cordova/)